# Databricks connect cannot configure default credentials via VSCode

Tags: vscode-extensions, databricks-connect

I configured the `.databrickscfg` to a host which I then authenticate with OAuth. I can successfully make use of the function `Upload and Run File on Databricks` within VSCode.

However, now I try to run this cell from a Jupyter notebook file in VScode:

```
from databricks.connect.session import DatabricksSession as SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

which yields the following error:

```
default auth: cannot configure default credentials. Config: host=X, auth_type=metadata-service, cluster_id=Y. Env: DATABRICKS_HOST, DATABRICKS_AUTH_TYPE, DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID
```

I was expecting no difference between the `Upload and Run File on Databricks` and the Jupyter Notebook environment. Anyone any ideas what's going wrong?